# Should I use Activities or Views with tabs & lists?

Tags: android

I'm new to Java & Android development.  I'm trying to develop an app that has 2 tabs, 1 tab has a listview inside of it.  When you click on an item in the list, it takes you to another list.. and then you select another item, onto another list, ect.. until they reach the final page which I have setup as a non-selectable list.  My question is.. should I create a new activity every time the user clicks on an item in the list? Or is that something normally done with changing views? If done with views, doesn't that pretty much disable their use of going back with the back button?

In the other tab I have an area with a list I guess in which you can remove items off of the list.. Now would I create a new activity for this and put this tab activity on every activity of the lists? I guess this part is what got me confused.. if I hadn't had the other tab my current setup of creating a new activity as the user drills down the lists worked just fine.

This all might sounds a little confusing but let me know if you guys need further explanation..

Comment: Did you already read the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515840/android-activities-vs-views ? I know it's not exactly about lists, but I think it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use changeable views only when the views are conceptually showing the same data from a different viewpoint.  Since you say "it takes you to another list", I'd say use a separate activity.

As for the tab, my understanding is that you can model each tab as a separate activity, I'm not clear on why you would "put this tab activity on every activity of the lists"?  Are you saying that one tab (the "remove" tab) is dependent on what's showing on the other tab ("the list tab")?  Without knowing more about the context, but first instinct would be to use a separate "remove tab" activity and model the tab host as having separate activities per tab.

Comment: Ah, alright. I think you've answered my question then.. I should use a different activity for every new list that is shown after the user selects an item in the list.. Now as for the tab. The selectable lists are held within a tab, but when I create a new tab initially it goes away on new list activities, so what I've done is created a new tabhost in every activity to show the other tab.. Is that correct? Or is there a way to show the tab across all activities..?

Comment: @Brendan - Sorry you didn't get more answers for comparison. I'm no expert. Multiple tab hosts seems simplest.  If you have time and/or get curious, you can experiment with other approaches.  I don't know of about tutorials/examples of more sophisticated tab host usage.  If I come across any, I'll add them here.